# Does Go (deep) copy keys when inserting into a map?

Tags: dictionary, go, key

I have a `map` with complex keys - for example, 2D arrays:

```
m := make(map[[2][3]int]int)
```

When I insert a new key into the map, does Go make a deep copy of the key?

```
a := [2][3]int{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
m[a] = 1
```

In other words, if I change the array `a` after using it as a map key, does the map still contain the old value of `a`?

Comment: Arrays in Go are pass-by-value (as opposed to slices, which are pass-by-reference), so this is no different than doing `a := 1; m[a] = 1`; after the map assignment has been executed, the key and the variable are unrelated (except that they may still have the same value unless you change one of them).

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, it is copied.

By specification, Arrays are `value types`.

> Go's arrays are values. An array variable denotes the entire array; it is not a pointer to the first array element (as would be the case in C). This means that when you assign or pass around an array value you will make a copy of its contents. (To avoid the copy you could pass a pointer to the array, but then that's a pointer to an array, not an array.)
>   https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

See for yourself:

https://play.golang.org/p/fEUYWwN-pm

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    m := make(map[[2][3]int]int)
    a := [2][3]int{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

    fmt.Printf("Pointer to a: %p\n", &a)

    m[a] = 1
    for k, _ := range m {
        fmt.Printf("Pointer to k: %p\n", &k)
    }
}
```

The pointers do not match.

EDIT: The real reason is when inserting into a map, the key value is copied.  Or, you can continue to just remember the rule above: arrays are value types and their reuse denotes a copy.  Either works here.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are always passed by value, so, yes in this case Go will make a deep copy of the key.

From the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice. If the key type is an interface type, these comparison operators must be defined for the dynamic key values; failure will cause a run-time panic.

The keys are copied into the map.  Excluding `map` and `slice` as valid keys means that the keys can't change.  Note that go doesn't follow pointers if you define a map type with a pointer as a key (eg `map[*int]int`) it compares the pointers directly.

Comment: I'd be a bit more cautious with the word "deep" here: inserting a value into a map copies the key's *value,* and that's all there is to it. Since everythng in Go is passed/copied by value when we talk about language primitives (assignment operator, passing arguments to functions), this is what happens with the values of the map keys. The Go compiler explicitly analyzes the type used as the key of each map to trap attempts of using reference types for that -- directly or embedded into a struct type.

Comment: IOW, such copying is not "deep" or "shallow"; it's copying of a value as defined by the Go spec.  And since the map keys can't use types with referece semantics, the copying always happen to be "deep" in its outcome but it's not that it is somehow *defined* to be deep as opposed to shallow -- it's just a byproduct of how values are passed/copied in Go ;-)